Creating an Index using PCA?
Apologies if this question seems basic—I'm new to PCA. In R, I've figured out how to obtain the component loadings and scores. To create an index, should I simply add these scores together? In other words, are the scores already projected into the new space? Additionally, if we want to use three components, do we simply add the scores or do we need to weight them? Thank you
